# Monodroid raises error

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying run simple code which is generated by default when you create new project in Visual Studio. Emulator raises exception. It is evalution version of Mono for Android. Why that error happens? Thanks.

Here code

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace MonoAndroidApplication1
{
[Activity(Label = "MonoAndroidApplication1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
    }
}
}
```

Here error

Tried to launch activity 'MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1/monoandroidapplication1.Activity1', but the device could not find it.

A common cause of this is manually adding an  to your AndroidManifest.xml whose name does not match your Activity class.

Consider using the [Activity] attribute instead:
http://monodroid.net/Tutorials/Working_with_AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Did the application get successfully installed on your device?  You can check if there is an icon for it in the app tray, or check the Settings -> Applications screen.

My guess is that the app isn't successfully installing for some reason, and the IDE isn't properly detecting the failure.

Comment: Seems yes. I do not see installed application on my virtual device. I have no any ideas. Maybe possible check log files somewhere?

Comment: Go to Tools->Options->Mono for Android and turn on ADB Logging.  This will write a log to your desktop that should have the failure message somewhere in it.

Answer (score -1):

```
Here information from log file 

    -- Starting Process - 30.06.2011 23:41:35 --
Executable: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: start-server
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin
[STDOUT] 
-- Process Finished [5000] --
-- Starting Process - 30.06.2011 23:41:36 --
Executable: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: -s emulator-5554 install "C:\MonoDroid\MonoAndroidApplication2\MonoAndroidApplication2\bin\Debug\MonoAndroidApplication2.MonoAndroidApplication2-Signed.apk"
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin
[STDOUT]    pkg: /data/local/tmp/MonoAndroidApplication2.MonoAndroidApplication2-Signed.apk
[STDOUT] 
[STDOUT] Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
[STDOUT] 
[STDERR] 72 KB/s (139602 bytes in 1.883s)
-- Starting Process - 30.06.2011 23:41:54 --
Executable: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: start-server
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin
[STDOUT] 
[STDERR] 
-- Process Finished [5000] --
-- Starting Process - 30.06.2011 23:41:54 --
Executable: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n MonoAndroidApplication2.MonoAndroidApplication2/monoandroidapplication2.Activity1
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin
[STDOUT] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=MonoAndroidApplication2.MonoAndroidApplication2/monoandroidapplication2.Activity1 }
[STDOUT] 
[STDOUT] Error type 3
[STDOUT] 
[STDOUT] Error: Activity class {MonoAndroidApplication2.MonoAndroidApplication2/monoandroidapplication2.Activity1} does not exist.
[STDOUT] 

So the error is INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES. How to resolve it? Thanks.
```

Comment: You should edit your question and put that in a code block. It's not a solution.

Comment: I've reinstalled mono at emulator and currently it works without errors. But I still do not understand why it happend. Anyway thanks for your help.