# Monodroid default application in VS2010 fails to run with "activity not found" error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I have installed MonoDroid (and all prerequisites) and trying to run the default Android project in VS2010.
This is the code:

```
[Activity(Label = "MonoAndroidApplication1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]  
public class Activity1 : Activity  
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
    }
}
```

When running the application an error is returned:

> Tried to launch activity 'MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1/monoandroidapplication1.Activity1', but the device could not find it.
>
> A common cause of this is manually adding an  to your AndroidManifest.xml whose name does not match your Activity class.
>
> Consider using the [Activity] attribute instead:
>   http://monodroid.net/Tutorials/Working_with_AndroidManifest.xml

I have installed the Android SDK in C:\Android_SDK and accordingly set the location in Tools->Options->Mono for Android.

Mono also seems to be correctly installed on the emulator and this is the final bit of log from ADB:

```
-- Process Finished [5000] --  
-- Starting Process - 17/08/2011 12:01:03 --  
Executable: C:\Android_SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe  
Arguments: -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Users\***************\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\bin\Debug\MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1-Signed.apk"  
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin  
[STDOUT]    pkg: /data/local/tmp/MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1-Signed.apk  
[STDOUT]  
[STDOUT] Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]  
[STDOUT]  
[STDERR] 696 KB/s (139717 bytes in 0.196s)  
-- Starting Process - 17/08/2011 12:01:05 --  
Executable: C:\Android_SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe  
Arguments: start-server  
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin  
[STDOUT]  
[STDERR]  
-- Process Finished [5000] --  
-- Starting Process - 17/08/2011 12:01:05 --  
Executable: C:\Android_SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe  
Arguments: -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1/monoandroidapplication1.Activity1  
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin  
[STDOUT] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1/monoandroidapplication1.Activity1 }  
[STDOUT]  
[STDOUT] Error type 3  
[STDOUT]  
[STDOUT] Error: Activity class{MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1/monoandroidapplication1.Activity1} does not exist.  
[STDOUT]
```

This post [Monodroid raises error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532103/monodroid-raises-error) is about the same error but reinstalling Mono on the emulator doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono for Android is not compatible with Java 7.  Uninstall Java 7, install Java 6, and try again.

Comment: Perhaps make monodroid display an error when it encounters Java7 until the issues are fixed.

Comment: Thanks @jpobst! Should have paid more attention to the install guide (http://android.xamarin.com/Installation/Visual_Studio).  Btw, because recent versions of the Android SDK break if there are spaces in the install location, I also had to copy the content of C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Novell into a C:\Android\Novell folder and change the C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Novell\Novell.MonoDroid.Common.targets accordingly (ResolveSdks task, set MonoAndroidFrameworkPath to a property with Value = "C:\Android\Novell").

Comment: @CodeInChaos Yeah, I made that change earlier today so you get an informative error message if Java 6 can't be found.  :)

Comment: @Strillo The fix for that is to uninstall the Android SDK and reinstall it to a place without spaces.  Nothing else should be needed.  Google has marked that bug as fixed in their bug tracker, but haven't done a new release yet.

Comment: @jpobst I've installed the Android SDK inside c:\Android but MonoDroid installs its own copies of the platforms inside C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Novell. Those are the ones referenced inside the Novell.MonoDroid.Common.targets when sending the app to the emulator. With the default installation the "Install platform components" step lasts for ages and eventually fails with an "out of space" error. (PS: I'm on Win7 x64)

Comment: @Strillo The Install target in Novell.MonoDroid.Common.targets is not used.  This is handled by the IDE you are using.  Also make sure you let the IDE start the emulator for you or it will not have enough internal space to hold everything.  (Or you need to start the emulator with --partition-size 512.)